# Проблема создания хранимых процедур (пакетов) на Oracle pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Здравствуйте, у меня возникла проблема при создании пакета процедур Oracle, a именно не понятно как поступить с переменной, которой присваивается тип дата.
Вот текст моего пакета:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE emp_pkg IS
    PROCEDURE Add_Emp(EMPNOFIELD IN NUMBER, ENAMEFIELD IN VARCHAR2, JOBFIELD IN VARCHAR2, MGRFIELD IN NUMBER, HIREDATEFIELD IN DATE, SALFIELD IN NUMBER, COMMFIELD IN NUMBER, DEPTNOFIELD IN NUMBER);
    PROCEDURE Update_Emp(EMPNOFIELD IN NUMBER, ENAMEFIELD IN VARCHAR2, JOBFIELD IN VARCHAR2, MGRFIELD IN NUMBER, HIREDATEFIELD IN DATE, SALFIELD IN NUMBER, COMMFIELD IN NUMBER, DEPTNOFIELD IN NUMBER, B IN NUMBER);
     PROCEDURE Delete_Emp(EMPNOFIELD1 IN NUMBER);
END emp_pkg;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY emp_pkg IS
   PROCEDURE Add_Emp(EMPNOFIELD IN NUMBER, ENAMEFIELD IN VARCHAR2, JOBFIELD IN VARCHAR2, MGRFIELD IN NUMBER, HIREDATEFIELD IN DATE, SALFIELD IN NUMBER, COMMFIELD IN NUMBER, DEPTNOFIELD IN NUMBER)
   IS
    BEGIN
     INSERT INTO SCOTT.EMP(EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, HIREDATE, SAL, COMM, DEPTNO)
     VALUES(EMPNOFIELD, ENAMEFIELD, JOBFIELD, MGRFIELD, TO_DATE('HIREDATEFIELD', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), SALFIELD, COMMFIELD, DEPTNOFIELD);
   END Add_Emp;

   PROCEDURE Update_Emp(EMPNOFIELD IN NUMBER, ENAMEFIELD IN VARCHAR2, JOBFIELD IN VARCHAR2, MGRFIELD IN NUMBER, HIREDATEFIELD IN DATE, SALFIELD IN NUMBER, COMMFIELD IN NUMBER, DEPTNOFIELD IN NUMBER, B IN NUMBER)
   IS
   BEGIN
    UPDATE SCOTT.EMP
    SET EMPNO = EMPNOFIELD,
        ENAME = ENAMEFIELD,
        JOB = JOBFIELD,
        MGR = MGRFIELD,
        HIREDATE = HIREDATEFIELD,
        SAL = SALFIELD,
        COMM = COMMFIELD,
        DEPTNO =  DEPTNOFIELD
    WHERE EMPNO = B;
    END Update_Emp;

    PROCEDURE Delete_Emp(EMPNOFIELD1 IN NUMBER)
    IS
    BEGIN
     DELETE FROM SCOTT.EMP
     WHERE EMPNO = EMPNOFIELD1;
    END Delete_Emp;
END emp_pkg;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю правильно ли я поступил или нет, но я решил переменной HIREDATEFIELD присвоить тип VARCHAR2 и к моему удивлению заработало

Comment: И что, даже Add_emp работает с его TO_DATE('HIREDATEFIELD', 'DD-MM-YYYY')  вы тут не значение переменной преобразуете в DATE а просто текстовую строку :)

Comment: нет, я поступил с переменной HIREDATEFIELD, аналогично как и с переменными строчного типа

Comment: Я говорил исключительно про ваш пример процедуры в вопросе, там кавычки стоят, собственно и все :)

Comment: Нет, вы неправильно поступили. Опишите вашу проблему более подробно в вопросе.